# How to implement Redis cache with DXA 2.0 Java application

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, caching

We are using SDL Web 8.5 and DXA 2.0 Java for our website. We would like to incorporate client-side (Content Interaction Library(CIL)) caching to improve site performance. Is there any example or documentation available to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the SDL Documentation Content Delivery client configuration of [ServiceConfig](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-E03A051A-D5FE-480A-A333-FAAC1F9C2AAD) for Redis CIL cache.

**Example:**

```
<!--
A configuration sample for using Distributed Caching with Redis.
Please update the following fields:
    CacheUri - in case of Redis is set to Redis hostname with a port number;
    CacheClientId - should be the same for a bunch of CIL's which meant to be one environment;
    CachePassword - Redis cache password. Delete this field if Redis is used without a password;
-->
<ServiceConfig CacheEnabled="true" CacheUri="localhost:6379"
               ConnectionTimeout="10000" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ServiceAvailabilityCheck="true"
               CacheProviderClass="com.sdl.web.client.cache.distributed.RedisCacheProvider"
               CacheConnectionTimeout="10000"
               CacheClientId="defaultCacheClientId"
               CachePassword="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY="
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_client_conf.xsd">

    <DiscoveryService ServiceUri="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc"/>
    <TokenService ClientId="cduser" ClientSecret="encrypted:o/cgCBwmULeOyUZghFaKJA=="/>
</ServiceConfig>
```

[Configuring web application caching (Java)](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-4789E669-EAC4-4916-B832-5123FDE320DE)

**Updated:**

[Comparison Ehcache vs. Redis](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Ehcache%3BRedis)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Velmurugan thanks for your reply. Can u please also tell us  is there any advantage using Redis cache instead of echache (default caching)

Comment: Updated the answer to provided the reference link for Ehcache vs Redis comparison