# How to connect to Redis cache via ssl in DXA 2.0?

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

We have client and Redis which configured to use ssl.
What should I set in cd_client.xml to get connection with Redis via ssl?

Comment: Vitaly , Welcome to Stack Echange , Please let us know the Tridion Version and leyt us know is your web app is .Net or Java

Answer (score 2):

SDL Documentation  reference :

Configuring web application caching (Java) ->  [Link](https://docs.sdl.com/792164/574270/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-0/configuring-web-application-caching--java-)
Configuring web application caching (.NET) -> [Link](https://docs.sdl.com/784837/697618/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/configuring-web-application-caching---net-)

Refer to this [link](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19975/how-to-implement-redis-cache-with-dxa-2-0-java-application)  for more  details

Answer (score 0):

SDL DXA does not support Redis Distributed Cache.

*"Regarding the distributed Redis caching, note that DXA is a framework, for which RWS provides options, and which customers can tailor as per their business requirements.  The distributed Redis caching is an option to configure and implement.  If there are specific implementation questions which are not clear, we can ask for clarification on this.  DXA support is offered via a PS engagement subscription, but DXA itself is not a core product offering."*